# How to share PHP class files across two servers (front end and back end)

Tags: php, server

For security reasons, I would like to install the admin (back-end) of my website on a different server than the front-end server (www).

The front-end server uses PHP objects that will be required in the back-end in order to work properly (obviously).

What should I implement in order to be able to use on the back-end server a class that has been uploaded on the front end server?

As of right now, the only solution I can think of is to upload the class files on both servers but I don't know if it really is a reliable solution.

Thank you.

Comment: You mean like having a shared dependency? create a composer package, set up a local repo if it's a private piece of code (satis is good), and add it to the dependencies... This question is arguably off-topic for this site, as SO deals with specific code related problems, not development toolchains etc..

Comment: You are right, I did not think of composer packages, I will look into that. Thank you.

Comment: ... or you could set up NFS on something like Amazon Web Services

Comment: @Vincent: This is well worth checking out: a satis container so you can get it up and running quickly: https://github.com/ypereirareis/docker-satis

Answer (score 1):

You can use any type of rsync between the two servers, so that way you will always have a copy of what you want in both servers.

In our company we do have some replication servers, with the same problem as you. What we use is a Jenkins/Capistrano task, so when we upload the code, after passing tests, and so, we upload the shared code to different locations.

Comment: Thank you, I will look into that. For anyone facing the same issue, a composer package would also be an idea to look for (read Elias Van Ootegem's comment above)

Comment: This should've been a comment. Using rsync can work, but becomes problematic on distributed, horizontally scalable systems. It also doesn't allow for versioning, or different deployment strategies. There are some serious limitations to this approach: you're not taking everything into account. I'd argue using 2 repo's, and having git submodules would be a better fit than relying on CI + rsync

Comment: We have no issues on that, every opened instance if there are so, knows when the code has change with a broadcasting system under CI, and of course there is more than rsync behind, we use ansible and AWS, but I think that the problem explained does not need such a deep approach. Sometimes if the problem is simple, a simple solution can work.